# One cell too many with datatool and longtable

Tags: tex-core, longtable, datatool

I am aware of the previous post [datatool with longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42554/datatool-with-longtable), but it didn't solve my problem.

I've a document with 10 tables or so, for each table I use this piece of code:

```
\DTLsetseparator{;} 
\DTLloaddb{kundt2}{kundt2.csv}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\caption[De berekende bronsterkte van de buis]{De berekende bronsterkte van de buis} \label{tbl:kundt2} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\DTLforeach{kundt2}{
\1=1, \2=2, \3=3}{\ifthenelse{\value{DTLrowi}>0}{
\1 & \2 & \3 \\ \hline }{}} 
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

My csv file

```
1;2;3;
444;555;666;
111;222;333;
```

etc., I know that one is fine.

Since I'm Dutch I need to use the `;` sign for separating my csv values. Everything is working great even for tables longer then 4 pages but every single time there is an extra empty cell at the last row. I tried to change this line:

```
\DTLforeach{kundt2}{
\1=1, \2=2, \3=3}{\ifthenelse{\value{DTLrowi}>0}{
\1 & \2 & \3 \\ \hline }{}}
```

to:

```
\DTLforeach{kundt2}{
\1=1, \2=2, \3=3}{\ifthenelse{\value{DTLrowi}>0}{
\\ \hline \1 & \2 & \3}{}}
```

But then I get the extra empty cell at the first row. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

datatool apparently doesn't protect its internals enough to be used in this context. You can hide the switching in `\noalign` as below. I also removed the center environment as it has no effect on longtable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool,longtable}

\begin{document}
\DTLsetseparator{;} 
\DTLloaddb{kundt2}{kundt2.csv}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\caption[De berekende bronsterkte van de buis]{De berekende bronsterkte van de buis} \label{tbl:kundt2} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\noalign\bgroup
\DTLforeach{kundt2}{
\1=1, \2=2, \3=3}{\egroup\ifthenelse{\value{DTLrowi}>0}{
\1 & \2 & \3 \\ \hline }{}\noalign\bgroup}\egroup
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]