# How to get rid of two vertical lines in a longtable

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable

I have two mysterious lines in my longtable and even tho I have seen other questions regarding problems with vertical lines, I have not found any solution to my problem yet. I can see that it´s produced by DTLforeach but I can´t solve it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\ProcessN}{}

\UseRawInputEncoding
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLrawmap{§}{\S}

\begin{filecontents*}{processer.csv}
Behandling;Punktnotation process;Processnamn
B;2.8.3;IT
B;3.1.1;Administration
B;3.1.1;Administration
B;3.1.3.1;Testsite
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5cm}|p{12.5cm}|}\hline%
\rowcolor{YellowOrange}%
\textbf{Process}&\textbf{Namn på process} \\%
\hline%
\endhead%
\hline \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Tabellen fortsätter på nästa sida}} \\%
\endfoot%
\endlastfoot%

\DTLloadrawdb{processer}{processer.csv}%
\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Behandling}{B}\and\not\DTLiseq{\PunktnotationP}{\ProcessN}]{processer}%
{\Processnamn=Processnamn,%
  \Behandling=Behandling,%
  \PunktnotationP=Punktnotation process}{\PunktnotationP&\Processnamn\\\hline%
  \global\let\ProcessN\PunktnotationP}%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

THe output it produces and the problem shown:
[image]

/Softest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42637/3929

You'll probably need to rewrite it like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\ProcessN}{}

\UseRawInputEncoding
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLrawmap{§}{\S}

\begin{filecontents*}{processer.csv}
Behandling;Punktnotation process;Processnamn
B;2.8.3;IT
B;3.1.1;Administration
B;3.1.1;Administration
B;3.1.3.1;Testsite
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5cm}|p{12.5cm}|}\hline%
\rowcolor{YellowOrange}%
\textbf{Process}&\textbf{Namn på process} \\%
\hline%
\endhead%
\hline \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Tabellen fortsätter på nästa sida}} \\%
\endfoot%
\hline
\endlastfoot%
\DTLloadrawdb{processer}{processer.csv}%
\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Behandling}{B}\and\not\DTLiseq{\PunktnotationP}{\ProcessN}]{processer}%
{\Processnamn=Processnamn,%
  \Behandling=Behandling,%
  \PunktnotationP=Punktnotation process}{%
  \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\\hline}%
  \PunktnotationP&\Processnamn%
  \global\let\ProcessN\PunktnotationP}%
\end{longtable}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I need some practice in searching :)
It works like a charm.